# HTML/CSS links clickable area considerably larger than intended

Tags: css, html

I have a page made up of 4 photographs with text underneath them that are the links for navigating the site. Everything works, except that the active area for the link extends the entire length of the page once it begins. I can move the mouse well under the pictures and text and it still activates the hover.

The site can be found [here](http://test.thecodepixie.com). I can add the code here if need be, just thought being able to see the whole thing might help!

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `height: 420px`; from .photography, .cinematography, .contact  and .about.
I have tested it, it works fine on firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `height: 420px;` from `.photography` and others as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing some Firebug work on it, but Firebug is being a bit - well, buggy, on me lately.

Try either removing the `height:240px`, or try removing the `padding-top`. It seems like one of those is causing the issue, because it's blowing out the CSS Box Model, and making it think the link is that large.

It's because you're using the classes on each anchor, it's making them too big.

Comment: I did the same with the developer tool in chrome and i got exactly the same result you got in both cases

Answer (score 0):

keep the `height: 420px;`,  remove the `padding-top` and add this `line-height:850px`, It'll fix it